# Flexbox image match container height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 4 images on my site and display 2 vertically with 2 horizontal images next to these in a grid.

The problem I'm having is that the images line up correctly when the page is desktop size but when it is scaled down to mobile the images will scale differently and look out of alignment

As you can see the vertical images on the left don't scale to fit the container height, is there a way to stretch these images to match the container height?

How can I get the images to stay aligned at all times?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.home-promo-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.home-promo-cell {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.gridA {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.gridB {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.gridB .cell:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.gridB .cell:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.text-vertical {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba( 255,255,255,0.6);
  padding: 20px;
}

.inner-cell-vertical:hover .text-vertical {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  transition: background 0.8s ease;
}

.inner-cell-vertical {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ff00ff;
}

.inner-cell-vertical img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.inner-cell-vertical::after {
  content:'\A';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    animation-name: fadeFromtop;
        -webkit-animation-name: fadeFromtop;
        animation-duration: 300ms;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 300ms;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-cell-vertical:hover .text {
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(50%);

}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  display: flex;
}

a:hover .inner-cell-vertical:after {
  animation-name: fadeFromBottom;
        -webkit-animation-name: fadeFromBottom;
        animation-duration: 300ms;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 300ms;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        opacity:1;
        overflow: hidden;
}


@keyframes fadeFromBottom  {
        0%{
            opacity:0;
            -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
            -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
            -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
            -o-transform: translateY(100%);
            transform: translateY(100%);
        }
        100%{
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
            -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
            -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
            -o-transform: translateY(0px);
            transform: translateY(0px);
            display: block;
        }
    }
@keyframes fadeFromtop  {
    0%{
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
        -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(400%);
        -o-transform: translateY(100%);
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="home-promo-wrap">
  <div class="home-promo-cell">
    <div class="gridA">
      <div class="cell">
        <a>
        <div class="inner-cell-vertical">
        <div class="text-vertical">
          <h2>

          </h2>
        <p class="text-desc">
        </p>
        </div><img class="img-responsive" src="https://plissee-jalousien-rollos.de/media/wysiwyg/categories_1_1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <a>
          <div class="inner-cell-vertical">
            <div class="text-vertical">
              <h2>

              </h2>
            <p class="text-desc">
            </p>
            </div>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://plissee-jalousien-rollos.de/media/wysiwyg/categories_1_1.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="home-promo-cell">
    <div class="gridB">
      <div class="cell">
        <a>
            <div class="inner-cell-vertical">
              <div class="text-vertical">
                <h2>

                </h2>
              <p class="text-desc">
              </p>
              </div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://plissee-jalousien-rollos.de/media/wysiwyg/categories_1_3.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <a>
            <div class="inner-cell-vertical">
              <div class="text-vertical">
                <h2>

                </h2>
              <p class="text-desc">
              </p>
              </div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://plissee-jalousien-rollos.de/media/wysiwyg/categories_1_4.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Images have different sizes and the CSS says that their height should be "auto", so they align almost perfectly only in certain conditions: approximately from 1600px to 1700px width screen.

Comment: Your images do align perfectly , I don't know what you're meaning?

Comment: How does `object-fit` not work in the way you want?

Comment: I also updated my answer with a sample using `background-image`.

Comment: I couldn't get object-fit to work with my code and the browser support is too limited for me at the moment but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If to keep the `img` you could use `object-fit`.

*Note, `object-fit` has limits when it comes to browser support: [https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit_)*

*If you need better browser support, here is a sample using `background-image`: [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y4o8ohj7/1/).

The main with this version is to set a height and nested flex containers.*

Stack snippet

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.home-promo-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.home-promo-cell {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.gridA {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.gridB {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.gridB .cell:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.gridB .cell:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.text-vertical {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba( 255,255,255,0.6);
  padding: 20px;
}

.inner-cell-vertical:hover .text-vertical {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  transition: background 0.8s ease;
}

.inner-cell-vertical {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ff00ff;
}

.inner-cell-vertical img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;               /*  changed  */
  display: block;
  overflow:hidden;
  object-fit: cover;          /*  added  */
}

.inner-cell-vertical::after {
  content:'\A';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    animation-name: fadeFromtop;
        -webkit-animation-name: fadeFromtop;
        animation-duration: 300ms;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 300ms;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-cell-vertical:hover .text {
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(50%);

}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  display: flex;
}

a:hover .inner-cell-vertical:after {
  animation-name: fadeFromBottom;
        -webkit-animation-name: fadeFromBottom;
        animation-duration: 300ms;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 300ms;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        opacity:1;
        overflow: hidden;
}


@keyframes fadeFromBottom  {
        0%{
            opacity:0;
            -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
            -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
            -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
            -o-transform: translateY(100%);
            transform: translateY(100%);
        }
        100%{
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
            -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
            -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
            -o-transform: translateY(0px);
            transform: translateY(0px);
            display: block;
        }
    }
@keyframes fadeFromtop  {
    0%{
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
        -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(400%);
        -o-transform: translateY(100%);
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="home-promo-wrap">
  <div class="home-promo-cell">
    <div class="gridA">
      <div class="cell">
        <a>
        <div class="inner-cell-vertical">
        <div class="text-vertical">
          <h2>

          </h2>
        <p class="text-desc">
        </p>
        </div><img class="img-responsive" src="https://plissee-jalousien-rollos.de/media/wysiwyg/categories_1_1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <a>
          <div class="inner-cell-vertical">
            <div class="text-vertical">
              <h2>

              </h2>
            <p class="text-desc">
            </p>
            </div>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://plissee-jalousien-rollos.de/media/wysiwyg/categories_1_1.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="home-promo-cell">
    <div class="gridB">
      <div class="cell">
        <a>
            <div class="inner-cell-vertical">
              <div class="text-vertical">
                <h2>

                </h2>
              <p class="text-desc">
              </p>
              </div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://plissee-jalousien-rollos.de/media/wysiwyg/categories_1_3.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <a>
            <div class="inner-cell-vertical">
              <div class="text-vertical">
                <h2>

                </h2>
              <p class="text-desc">
              </p>
              </div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://plissee-jalousien-rollos.de/media/wysiwyg/categories_1_4.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe its a one line change at line number 64 in the css.

`height: auto;` to `height: 100%;`

```
.inner-cell-vertical img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here is the [Pen](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/LQbpxj). Please let me know whether this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this will _stretch_ and distort the image. Try one with a different ratio and you'll see.

Comment: @LGSon That's what the actual question is, "Is there a way to stretch these images to match the container height".

Comment: Stretch, yes, distort/break aspect ratio, no.

Comment: @tom-harrison, In that case, you may consider setting the images as a `background-image` to maintain aspect ration with browser support.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions but neither of these options seem to work the way I wanted so I will likely resort to using background-image